# How to solve "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."?

Tags: python, dll, importerror, dllimport, mediapipe

This is the code, I'm trying to run:

```
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector=HandDetector(maxHands='1')

while True:
    success, img =cap.read()
    hands, img= detector.findHands(img)

    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(' '):
        break
```

and I get this error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

here the detailed error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataCollection.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
  File "C:\Users\PMLS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 10, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "C:\Users\PMLS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "C:\Users\PMLS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\mediapipe\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I want the hand detector to work well as it was in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wa2ARoUUdU8) that I'm following through.

Here the solutions I've tried:

1. Reinstalling cvzone and mediapipe [didn't work]
2. Checked Dependencies and installed numpy,  absl-py, attrs, flatbuffers, matplotlib, numpy, opencv-contrib-python, protobuf for mediapipe [didn't work]
3. Look for dll file in mediapipe directory which I found as file named "opencv_world3410.dll" there is no other dll files. I added the path for the opencv_world3410.dll into environment variables PATH. [didn't work even after I restarted my pc] **I'm also not sure if this is the required dll file ?**
4. Check versions I installed the mediapipe and cvzone just today hence these are the latest version available.
5. Here I found out by [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com) that this command
   `pip install msvc-runtime` works for some people. I've tried that too and its same error.

Is there any thing else I could try to solve the issue?
here the versions of mediapipe, cvzone, cv2 and python

```
Python 3.7.9
mediapipe 0.9.0.1
cv2 4.9.0
cvzone 1.6.1
```

Please guide me on how to remove this error.
Thank You in Advance.